# What is most concise way to check for null or whitespace before displaying data in Blazor components?

Tags: blazor, null-check

I would like to reduce the amount of code in the following code block:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee?.HomeAddressStreet))
{
    @employee?.HomeAddressStreet<br />
}
```

Ideally, I would like one line of code without logic to decipher.  Something like this:

```
<Maybe Value="@employee?.HomeAddressStreet">@employee.HomeAddressStreet<br /></Maybe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a razor component named **Maybe.razor**:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Value))
    @ChildContent

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```